# Implementation of partitionM

Tags: haskell, monads

I needed a monadic version of [`partition`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:partition) today. I settled on the following version:

```
partitionM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m ([a], [a])
partitionM p xs = bimap (map fst) (map fst) . partition snd . zip xs <$> mapM p xs
```

Then I realized it's already implemented [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.6.14/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html):

> ```
> partitionM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m ([a], [a])
> partitionM f [] = return ([], [])
> partitionM f (x:xs) = do
>     res <- f x
>     (as,bs) <- partitionM f xs
>     return ([x | res]++as, [x | not res]++bs)
> ```

This second version doesn't have to pull in extra packages and doesn't create intermediate lists, but mine is shorter and doesn't have explicit recursion. What do you think of my solution in comparison with the library's implementation?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't use `foldM` and get the best of all worlds: no explicit recursion, no extra dependencies, and no need for an extra `<$>` over top of `mapM`.

Comment: `foldM` would end up with reversed lists if you appended to the front of the accumulator, would you not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This second version doesn't have to pull in extra packages…

`Data.Bifunctor` is part of `base` since 4.8.0.0, so I'm not sure where you get the "extra packages" from. Yes, `Data.Bifunctor` was originally in the `bifunctors` package, but it was [transferred into `base` in 2015](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/libraries/base/changelog.md).

However, compared to the `extras` version, your variant is easy to read, as the `[x | res] … [x | not res]` slightly obfuscates the result. I'd probably bind `map fst`, but that's personal preference.

> and doesn't create intermediate lists

It generates *a lot* of intermediate lists. I haven't checked yet, but as `[x|res]++as` depends on `res` cannot get simplified to `x:as` or `as` at compile time by rules, so it might create a thunk `[…]++as`. In the end, you have \$\mathcal O(n) \$ additional \$\mathcal O(1)\$-sized lists.

Since this is a hidden implementation detail, I don't really like Neil's solution too much. Something along

```
partitionM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m ([a], [a])
partitionM f [] = return ([], [])
partitionM f (x:xs) = do
    res <- f x
    (as,bs) <- partitionM f xs
    return $ if res then (x : as,     bs)
                    else (    as, x : bs)
```

would at least support the optimizer and get rid of those intermediate lists, but is even more verbose. Your variant uses an additional list, sure, but it's easier to read and to understand IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

This version uses only `base`, doesn't create extra lists and has no explicit recursion. The amount of plumbing this requires disturbs me - there ought to be a library out there that makes these building blocks fit together without naming `acc` and `res`.

```
partitionM f = foldrM (\x acc -> (\res -> bool second first res (x:) acc) <$> f x) ([], [])
```